# Where does Spring pick up the SSL Certificate?

Tags: java, spring, ssl

We have several Spring applications that stopped working because the certificate expired. At first, I just updated the keystore.jks file but on restart, the application still picked up the old cert. I even tried completely rebuilding the keystore.jks files.  Still not working correctly.

I next tried modifying the application.yml file by adding

```
server:
  port: 7777
  ssl:
    key-store: /etc/pki/tls/pfx/star.lereta.net.pfx
    key-store-password: "********"
```

On restart, the applicaton *still* picks up the expired certs.

This is running on CentOS 7 with Oracle Java.

```
/usr/bin/java -version

java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

I am not a Java programmer but I could probably fix a problem if it's not too bad.  However, to do that, I need to know what needs fixing.  Where could this darned thing be picking up the cert from?

edited to add:

Stepping through the jar file I discovered that the path was, in fact, hard-coded.  I do not have access to the source code but I finally figured out that the hard coded value could be overwritten by creating a file called application-ssl.yml.  I added the following and all is, more-or-less, well now:

```
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: ${myKeyStore}
    key-store-password: ${myKeyStorePassword}
    key-store-type: PKCS12
```

Comment: Do you have anything in front of the javaapp like f.x. a loadbalancer which could have a SSL Certificate?

Comment: it could be helpful if you could post a stacktrace

Comment: > Do you have anything in front of the javaapp like f.x. a loadbalancer which could have a SSL Certificate?

No load balancer or proxy involved.

> it could be helpful if you could post a stacktrace.

Where would I find that?

Comment: Something happen to the markdown formatting?

Comment: If you have found a solution, you can post a dedicated answer below your question instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping through the jar file I discovered that the path was, in fact, hard-coded. I do not have access to the source code but I finally figured out that the hard coded value could be overwritten by creating a file called application-ssl.yml. I added the following and all is, more-or-less, well now:

```
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: ${myKeyStore}
    key-store-password: ${myKeyStorePassword}
    key-store-type: PKCS12
```